# Removing duplicate adjacent value in a matrix R

Tags: r

I have a text file where inside it have 30 rows and around 1000 columns.The data layout when I use read.table and use View() is as shown below. I have try a lot methods use to remove duplicate adjacent value for data.frame to remove in my case but not work.

```
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

My expected the output would be something like this:

```
1 2 3 2
2
```

After I filter the duplicate, I will write it back into a new matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `rle`. It "[c]ompute[s] the lengths and values of runs of equal values in a vector".

```
DF <- read.table(text = "1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2")

x <- apply(DF, 1, function(x) unname(rle(x)$values))

do.call(rbind, lapply(x, `length<-`, max(lengths(x))))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    2    3    2
#[2,]    2   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: Any reason why `[c]ompute[s]` and not `computes`?

Comment: @zx8754 Well, in `help("rle")` it is "Compute". I'm just following rules for quoting.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. But now I have like many NAs in a row, i try to filter function to remove all the NAs but it is still remain in my table x. Is there another way?

Comment: Empty cells are not possible in a matrix or data.frame. Why are you bothered by the `NA` values?

Comment: Because I afraid it will take up a lot of memory and I like have 1 row data only 1-4 column have a value all the 2000 column are NA. But as long as I can retrieve the value out then it is ok. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome to use the list in `x` directly. Nobody forces you to use a matrix-like structure.

Comment: Ok noted, thank you for the hints, the reason why I use matrix is because all the row data have to be separated and not combine so that later when I need to read data row by row.